# Python function returns result but also 'none' at the very end

Tags: python, return

I'm a python beginner and want to return the amounts of sheep dependend on (n). I figured it out so far, but it also gives me a 'none statement' at the end of my results for instance:

"1sheep... 2sheep... 3sheep... 4sheep... 5sheep... None"

Here is the code:

```
def dunno(n):

    if n==0:
        return("0 sheep...")
    elif n==1:
        return("1 sheep...")
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            print("{}sheep...".format(i), end = " ")
```

I guess it has something to do with a needed return statement, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for reading/helping me out!

Comment: what do you expect to return?

Comment: just to note - your `elif` is duplicating the functionality in the for (when n=1, the range is `[1]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've a print statement and not a return statement in the else part.
So you are not returning the result, instead you are printing it and returning None.

You could store it in a list and return it for the expected behavior.

```
def dunno(n):

    if n==0:
        return("0 sheep...")
    elif n==1:
        return("1 sheep...")
    else:
        result = ["{}sheep...".format(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
        return " ".join(result)
```